# Compare Factory Design Pattern with a regular pattern

Tags: php, design-patterns

I was checking out factory design pattern and the below code was written as an example

```
<?php

abstract class AbstractClass {


    abstract public function from(): Product;

    function callClass(){
        return $this->from()->operation();
    }

}

class ClassA extends AbstractClass {

    public function from(): Product{
        return new ProductA();
    }
}

class ClassB extends AbstractClass {

   public function from(): Product{
        return new ProductA();
    }
}

interface Product {

    function operation(): string;
}

class ProductA implements Product {

    function operation(): string{
        return 'from product A';
    }
}

class ProductB implements Product {

    function operation(): string{
        return 'from product B';
    }
}

class ClientCode {

    function operate(AbstractClass $abstractClass){
        return $abstractClass->callClass();
    }
}


$code = new ClientCode();
$classA = new ClassA();
$c = $code->operate(new ClassB());
echo $c;
```

so when i was going through abstract documentation on php manual, i saw the below block of codes too

```
<?php

abstract class AbstractClass1 {

    abstract protected function getValue();

    function printValue(){
        echo $this->getValue();
    }
}


class ConCreteClassA extends AbstractClass1 {

    function getValue(){
        return 'from Concrete Class A';
    }

}

class ConCreteClassB extends AbstractClass1 {

    function getValue(){
        return 'from Concrete Class B';
    }

}

class ClientCode {
    
    function doSomething(AbstractClass1 $abs){
        return $abs->printValue();
    }
}


$clientCode = new ClientCode();

$result = $clientCode->doSomething(new ConCreteClassB());

echo $result;
```

so to me i feel like these two different codes could be used to achieve the same things..
I would like to whats the difference cause am just getting to understand design pattern along with abstract and interfaces...
Thanks all

Comment: The question has nothing to do with Factory Design Pattern. The difference is between [Abstract Class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) and [Object Interface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php). The former allow you to have both abstract methods and concrete methods, while the later one can only have abstract methods.

Comment: thanks..just get to read on object interface to understand better

Answer (score 1):

### Definition

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern),

> The Factory Method design pattern solves problems like:
>
> - How can an object be created so that subclasses can redefine which class to instantiate?
> - How can a class defer instantiation to subclasses?
>
> The Factory Method design pattern describes how to solve such problems:
>
> - Define a separate operation (factory method) for creating an object.
> - Create an object by calling a factory method.
>
> This enables writing of subclasses to change the way an object is created (to redefine which class to instantiate).

### Example

Imagine you are writing a simple web application like this:

```php
$app = new App();
$request = currentRequest(); // creates a request from environment
echo $app->handlePage($request); // print out the response
```

Let's say you want to write some code for caching. If you do not want to repeat yourself in writing caches, you'd want to write it as a separate class so you can reuse elsewhere, right?

```php
class App {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cache = new Cache();
    }
    public function handlePage(Request $request)
    {
        if ($cache = $this->cache->get('page:' . $request->getPageId()) {
            return $cache;
        }

        // Logics to generate response without cache
        // ...
        $this->cache->set('page:' . $request->getPageId(), $response);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

The cache class would probably look like this:

```php
class Cache
{
    public function set(string $key, $value)
    { ... }

    public function get(string $key)
    { ... }
}
```

#### A while later...

But some times later, your application got really popular. Many people comes to your site. You need to:

1. Have short-lived and user-specific cache for your users with login.
2. Have long-lived and really fast cache for the generic visitors (without login).

How should you change your code?

Of course you can modify your `Cache` class:

```php
class Cache
{
    public function set(Request $request, string $key, $value)
    {
        if ($request->hasUser()) {
            // ...
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }

    public function get(Request $request, string $key)
    {
        if ($request->hasUser()) {
            // ...
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

##### Problem

This design means your cache will be very specific to the application. Hence with this approach, you're forced to re-implementing the cache for every application.

#### Better Design 1: multiple caches

To stay true to the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle, you'd want cache classes to be specific to how you'd cache. Not specific to the application that uses it.

That means we'll have 2 caches:

```php
// Fast cache. But since memory is limited, need to expire fast.
class MemoryCache
{
    public function set(string $key, $value)
    { ... }

    public function get(string $key)
    { ... }
}

// Slower cache. But since disk is cheap, you can store many more
// and can expire slower.
class FileCache
{
    public function set(string $key, $value)
    { ... }

    public function get(string $key)
    { ... }
}
```

Then the application would also need to change.

```php
class App {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userCache = new FileCache();
        $this->visitorCache = new MemoryCache();
    }
    public function handlePage(Request $request)
    {
        if ($user = $request->getUser()) {
            // User logic
            $cache = $this->userCache->get(
                'page:' . $user->getId() . ':' . $request->getPageId());
            if ($cache) {
                return $cache;
            }

            // Logics to generate response without cache
            // ...
            $this->userCache->set(
                'page:' . $user->getId() . ':' . $request->getPageId());
            return $response;
        }

        // Visitor logic
        $cache = $this->visitorCache->get(
            'page:' . $request->getPageId());
        if ($cache) {
            return $cache;
        }

        // Logics to generate response without cache
        // ...
        $this->visitorCache->set(
            'page:' . $user->getId() . ':' . $request->getPageId());
        return $response;
    }
}

$app = new App();
$request = currentRequest();
echo $app->handlePage($request);
```

Notice we uses `$this->userCache` and `$this->visitorCache` in the naming. Of course we don't want to know they are memory cache or file cache. We are free to change using other cache implementations for them in the future.

##### Problem

Although problem solved, but notice the **user logic** and **visitor logic** blocks are awfully clumsy and duplicated.

Also both cache classes are simple `set()` and `get()`. We don't really need to separate the blocks simply because of caching. We don't even want to know how to use different cache!

If only we can only have 1 `$this->cache` in our code. If only both caches implementation can be used same way. Things will be much simpler.

#### Better Design 2: multiple caches implementations

OK. Let's only have 1 `$this->cache`.

```php
class App {
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        if ($user = $request->getUser()) {
            $this->cache = new FileCache(
              __DIR__ . '/../userCache/' . $user->getId() . '.cache');
        } else {
            $this->cache = new MemoryCache();
        }
    }

    public function handlePage(Request $request)
    {
        $cache = $this->cache->get('page:' . $request->getPageId());
        if ($cache) {
            return $cache;
        }

        // Logics to generate response without cache
        // ...
        $this->cache->set('page:' . $request->getPageId());
        return $response;
    }
}

$request = currentRequest();
$app = new App($request);
echo $app->handlePage($request);
```

A lot cleaner, right?

##### Problem

But there is one very significant change to the design. The App class now dictates which cache to use in the constructor. That means all methods within the App class will need to follow the same cache decision.

Imagine when you need to write another method to handle the About Us page (i.e. `handleAboutUs()`). Even if the about us page is the same for both visitor and user. Even if it does not change between user. It is forced to use file cache for user.

Also, now App needs to know awfully lot about `Request` in its constructor that we even need to change function call orders at the bottom. What if our caching logics need to know more things in the future?

Of course, we can fallback to have `$this->userCache` and `$this->visitorCache` separated. But that would be clumsy as hell.

Questions: Can we implement our cache in a common way but decide which cache to use **later**?

That way, we can gather more information along the line and be flexible in our methods.

#### Better Design 3: Factory pattern

Let's dedicate the cache selection logics to a factory class. Let it decide which cache implementation to get for my specific situation.

```php
class CacheFactory {
    public function getCache(Request $request, bool $userSpecific = false)
    {
        if ($userSpecific && $user = $request->getUser()) {
            return new FileCache(
              __DIR__ . '/../userCache/' . $user->getId() . '.cache');
        }
        return new MemoryCache();
    }
}
```

Then App can be rewritten:

```php
class App {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cacheFactory = new CacheFactory();
    }

    public function handlePage(Request $request)
    {
        // Get cache that is user specific
        $cacheHandler = $this->cacheFactory->getCache($request, true);
        if ($cache = $cacheHandler->get('page:' . $request->getPageId())) {
            return $cache;
        }

        // Logics to generate response without cache
        // ...
        $cacheHander->set('page:' . $request->getPageId());
        return $response;
    }

    public function handleAboutUs(Request $request)
    {
        // Get cache that is NOT user specific
        $cacheHandler = $this->cacheFactory->getCache($request, false);
        if ($cache = $cacheHandler->get('page:about-us')) {
            return $cache;
        }

        // Logics to generate response without cache
        // ...
        $cacheHander->set('page:about-us');
        return $response;
    }
}

$app = new App();
$request = currentRequest();
echo $app->handlePage($request);
```

Now:

1. App constructor needs to know nothing about the cache logics.
2. Each method can get a suitable cache from the factory class much later.
3. Each method still do not need to know the specific cache implementation! Method doesn't need to know anything about memory cache nor file cache. They just use them.

#### Conclusion of the Example

To conclude, Factory method separate implementation details (e.g. file cache and memory cache), programming concerns (e.g. user cache and visitor cache) and business logics (e.g. displaying of pages).

Think of other use case where Factory method is needed. Think about how you should implement them with Factory pattern, for example:

- **API controller:** depends on the "[Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept)" HTTP header, the factory would give you a different encoder to encode response (e.g. JSON, XML, YAML, HTML).
- **Payment service:** depends on the user account setting, the service will give you a different payment implementation that connects to different vendor (e.g. Stripe, PayPal)

### How do [Interface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) and [Abstract Class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) help with the Factory Pattern?

Software development is often a team effort. Also open source library users need helps to guide them using libraries correctly.

Correctly written [argument / return type declaration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php) makes programmer's life easier by:

1. Allow PHP to generate early and precise error when arguments are of incorrectly type; and
2. Provides IDE with information for [static analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_analysis). Then IDE can tell warn you about type errors even before running it. Also IDE can tell you how you can correctly use the libraries.

In our example, how the `CacheFactory` can describe what the `getCache` method returns?

```php
class CacheFactory {
    public function getCache(Request $request, bool $userSpecific = false): Cache
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now we have to declare what the `Cache` type is. Different cache backend have very different programming needs. It doesn't even make sense to write any default implementation of `set()` and `get()` methods.

[Object interface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) allows you to write class description with method that doesn't have a body:

```php
interface Cache
{
    public function set(string $key, $value);
    public function get(string $key);
}

class FileCache implements Cache {
    ...
}

class MemoryCache implements Cache {
    ...
}
```

When PHP notice that a class `implements` the `Cache` interface, it will check if the class matches all the required function signatures.

In Factory Pattern, It can serve as a contract between factory developer and user. The factory class will produce object that match the criteria. User can be certain that the produced object can be used in a certain way.

We can be certain that the following code will not be run by PHP if the contract is not met by the developer. Also IDE will prompt user to correct write the code.

```php
$cacheFactory = new CacheFactory();
$cacheFactory->getCache($request, true)->get('something');
```

What about abstract class?

Abstract class with abstract method is quite similar to interface. Writing Cache in the below way also works.

```php
abstract Cache
{
    abstract public function set(string $key, $value);
    abstract public function get(string $key);
}

class FileCache extends Cache {
    ...
}

class MemoryCache extends Cache {
    ...
}
```

But please note that PHP do not support multiple inheritance. An child class of `Cache` abstract class cannot also extends other class. That means it's hard for it to fulfil multiple type signatures.

This doesn't work:

```php
abstract Cache
{
    abstract public function set(string $key, $value);
    abstract public function get(string $key);
}

abstract GarbageCollector
{
    abstract public function gc(): bool;
}

class FileCache extends Cache, GarbageCollector {
    ...
}
```

But this would work:

```php
interface Cache
{
    public function set(string $key, $value);
    public function get(string $key);
}

interface GarbageCollector
{
    public function gc(): bool;
}

class FileCache implements Cache, GarbageCollector {
    ...
}
```

So interface is more flexible this way.

On the other hand, [abstract class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) can have mixed abstract and concrete method:

```php
abstract Cache
{
    private ?User $user = null;

    abstract public function setValue(string $key, $value);

    abstract public function getValue(string $key);

    public function set(string $key, $value) {
        if (!empty($this->user)) {
             $key = "user:{$user->getId()}:key:{$key}";
        } else {
             $key = "user:visitor:key:{$key}";
        }
        $this->setValue($key, $value);
    }

    public function get(string $key) {
        if (!empty($this->user)) {
             $key = "user:{$user->getId()}:key:{$key}";
        } else {
             $key = "user:visitor:key:{$key}";
        }
        return $this->getValue($key);
    }

    public function setUser(User $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?User {
        return $this->user;
    }
}

class FileCache extends Cache {
    public function set(string $key, $value) {
        // ...
    }
    public function get(string $key) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It all depends on how you want to design your class to meet your purpose.